# How to use Case on join SQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql

i have a query to select with case

```
select 
    so.name,
    rp.name,
    CASE WHEN sp.delivery_type = 'direct' THEN true ELSE false END as is_direct,
    CASE WHEN sp.origin ilike 'Return%' THEN true ELSE false END as is_from_return_doc,
    jsonb_agg(
        json_build_object(
            'id', sm.id,
            'product_id', pp.id,
            'product_sku', pt.default_code,
            'product_name', pt.name,
            'image_url', CASE WHEN ir.store_fname IS NOT NULL THEN CONCAT('{}', ir.store_fname) ELSE '' END,
            'quantity', sm.product_uom_qty,
            'uom', json_build_object(
                'id', sm_uom.id,
                'name', sm_uom.name,
                'factor', sm_uom.factor,
                'barcode', piu.barcode
            )
        )
    ) as items
from sale_order so
JOIN res_partner rp on
    so.partner_id = rp.id
JOIN stock_picking sp ON
    CASE 
        WHEN sp.sale_id = so.id and sp.origin = so.name and sp.state in ('done') THEN
            sp.sale_id = so.id
        WHEN sp.sale_id = so.id and sp.origin ilike 'Return%' and sp.state not in ('cancel', 'done') THEN
            sp.sale_id = so.id
    END
JOIN stock_move sm on
    sm.picking_id = sp.id
JOIN product_product pp on
    sm.product_id = pp.id
JOIN product_template pt on
    pp.product_tmpl_id = pt.id
JOIN product_uom sm_uom ON
    sm.product_uom = sm_uom.id
LEFT JOIN product_identity_uom piu ON
    piu.product_id = pt.id 
    AND piu.uom_id = sm.product_uom
LEFT JOIN ir_attachment ir ON
    ir.res_id = pt.id
    and ir.res_model = 'product.template'
    and ir.res_field = 'image'
WHERE
    so.name = 'SO503251'
GROUP BY
    so.id, rp.id, sp.id
```

on this part, i want the last condition is replacing the first condition if the second condition is true, but it always goes to the first condition..

so if we found the "return" it will replace the first condition,.. i tried to make it nest condition case in case but didnt work.. please can someone help?

```
CASE 
    WHEN sp.sale_id = so.id and sp.origin = so.name and sp.state in ('done') THEN
        sp.sale_id = so.id
    WHEN sp.sale_id = so.id and sp.origin ilike 'Return%' and sp.state not in ('cancel', 'done') THEN
        sp.sale_id = so.id
END
```

thanks

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you want to do -- an also an appropriate database tag.  I can confidently say that I've never needed to use `case` for a `join` expression, so there might be a better way to do what you want.

Comment: we can say there are 2 tables,
1. sale_order
2. stock_picking

then on sale_order can have multiple stock_pickings, we can say 2 stock_pickings related to 1 SO
then first stock_pickings is have criteria with first condition

WHEN sp.sale_id = so.id and sp.origin = so.name and sp.state in ('done') THEN
        sp.sale_id = so.id

and second stock_picking have criteria with the second condition

WHEN sp.sale_id = so.id and sp.origin ilike 'Return%' and sp.state not in ('cancel', 'done') THEN
        sp.sale_id = so.id

i want if the second condition is true, it will replace 1st

Answer (score 0):

I speculate that you want logic something like this:

```
ON sp.sale_id = so.id and
   (sp.origin = so.name and sp.state in ('done') or
    sp.origin ilike 'Return%' and sp.state not in ('cancel', 'done') 
   )
```

Comment: thanks but it will return 2 records, i want 1 record only